# Can I specify an intent sent via ADB?

Tags: eclipse, debugging, android-intent, adb

I'm developing an app that is designed to be launched (only) from another app which provides extras in the Intent. So this app does not use the LAUNCHER category in its intent filter, and does not launch and attach to the debugger when I start it from Eclipse.

It's very difficult to debug anything related to launching or the Intent, because I can only debug by adding the LAUNCHER category to the manifest and thus circumventing the intended method of starting the activity, without the necessary extras. Is there any way that I can specify the launch Intent sent by ADB to include the extra data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When facing similar challenge I was able to provide extras to the broadcast I was trying to send by switching to the URI form:

```
am broadcast "intent:#Intent;action=android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE;B.state=true;end"
```